# Как сделать выбор бронирования дат с календарем на 2 инпута?

Tags: javascript, calendar, календарь, daterangepicker

Используется вот этот [плагин](https://www.daterangepicker.com/) для реализации календаря.

На данный момент я его поправил и получил следующее

[image: календарь]

Моя задача реализовать немного по другому. Должно быть два input и один общий календарь. При выборе диапазона начальная дата ставится в первый инпут, а конечная во второй, при нажатии кнопки "ПРИМЕНИТЬ" закрываем календарь, а при нажатии на "Очистить" ставим в input что-то свое, например "Выберите дату".Так же не имеет значения какой input выбран первым.

Перекопал все настройки и код плагина, не смог найти как это скорректировать.

Также, нужна реализация для другого инпута менять подставляемое значение, например 11 авг - 15 авг, как найти какое именно значение сейчас установлено и подставить в строку.

Вот что должно быть в итоге

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения данной проблемы был использован вот этот плагин [AirDatapicker](http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/index-ru.html)

[Тут](https://github.com/Andreyneumyvannyi/TrainingProject-FSD-School/blob/master/src/components/dropdown/dropdown-date/dropdown-date.js) конфиг который решает эту задачу